# WinSCP -nopreservetime switch in .NET assembly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to add `-nopreservetime` to this code. I am not sure where or how to add it, I have tried different things to no result.

```
# Setup session options 
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions 
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp 
$sessionOptions.HostName = "#######.com" 
$sessionOptions.UserName = "#####" 
$sessionOptions.Password = "#####" 
$sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "#####" 
$sessionOptions.Timeout = "##" 

$TransferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $false 

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 
$Session.SessionLogPath = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Winscp\TEST\sessionlog.txt" 
$Session.debugLogPath = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Winscp\TEST\debugsessionlog"+$date+".txt"

try 
{ 
    Write-Host $date,("Connecting to FTP site.") 
    # Connect 
    $session.Open($sessionOptions) 
    Write-Host $date,("Connected to FTP site.") 

    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary 

    # Upload files, collect results 
    $transferResult = $session.PutFiles("$localPath", "$remotePath", $False, $transferOptions)
}
```

This is normally:

```
$transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath)
```

I am just trying to disable preserve timestamp. I have it off in the GUI but it isn't working in the `powershell_ise.exe`

The above code returns this in the log:

> 2015-07-20 08:52:44.635 Script: put -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -- "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Winscp############*.pdf" "/OUTGOING/TEST#####/##/"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TransferOptions.PreserveTimestamp`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions):

```
$transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False
```

See [Converting transfer settings scripting switches to code based on .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_from_script_transfer_settings).

---

You actually already have that piece of code there, but in a wrong place. You set a property of an uninitialized variable.

You have to move the line after the initialization of the `$transferOptions`:

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary 
$transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False
```